# jqueryUI datepicker not showing within ng-if directive of angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/qx9sxo8w/4/) where date picker is defined as

```
<div ng-if="show_d">
    <input id="date2" type="text" ng-model="date2">
  </div>
```

which is not fires the datepicker if that field is put inside `ng-if` directive.

Comment: Proper way is to use directive.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, when controller executes, the element `id="date2"` is not in `dom`. So event does not get attached. Use `ng-show/ng-hide` instead.

If you want to use ngIf, use it with directive(See [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vqrxf77y/)). Every time link get executed as ngIf evalutes to true and hence, your event get attach to 
it.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('datePicker', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      date: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      jQuery(element[0]).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        maxDate: '0',
        onSelect: function(date) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.date = date;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: `ng-show` works. But myself having complex DOM structure. So trying to dynamically create DOM based on some conditional expressions.

Comment: Something like this happens if using `ng-show` https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/qx9sxo8w/8/

Answer (score 0):

Use **ng-show** insted of **ng-if** directive, Since ng-if recreate the DOM and ng-show show/hide the DOM.